# how to use "terraform state pull" when state is in a statefile?

Tags: terraform

I store my states in separate state files:

```
state/project-1.tfstate
state/project-2.tfstate
```

I'm able to do "list" or "state" operations against a specific statefile, by providing a -state= flag:

```
$ terraform state list -state=state/project-1.tfstate
aws_acm_certificate.certificate
aws_lb.lb
aws_lb_listener.listener_http
aws_lb_listener.listener_https
aws_lb_target_group.tg
aws_lb_target_group_attachment.tg_attachemnt
```

or:

```
$ terraform state show -state=state/tools.tfstate aws_lb.lb
(...)
```

However - "terraform state pull" does not support -state flag.
It kind of makes sense, because we already have the state on disk in this case - but, terraform stores the files defined with -state= in a different format ("version": 4) than the normal terraform.tfstate ("version": 3).

I need to push these states to a remote and I'm not sure how else I could do it.

Comment: State migration should occur automatically after a prompt during a `plan`, unless you are asking about something different here.